# How do the executors check if a subscriber has something to do?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I’m looking into the lower levels of ROS2, specifically the executors. In the spin we use Executor::get_next_ready_executable to get the next AnyExecutable that has something do do (“Check the subscriptions to see if there are any that are ready”). At first, I interpreted this as looking for a subscriber that has a non-empty msgs queue. But the get_next_subscription only looks as group->can_be_taken_from, which does not depend (in an obvious way, maybe I have missed something) on the queue.

So how should I interpret these calls and how can I check if there really is anything to do for the subscribers? (Is there any other way than calling _take and check the bool* ‘taken’?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369969/how-do-the-executors-check-if-a-subscriber-has-something-to-do?/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2021-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So how should I interpret these calls and how can I check if there really is anything to do for the subscribers? (Is there any other way than calling _take and check the bool* ‘taken’?)

Currently the only way to know if there's any messages for a subscription is to put it into a waitset, call `rcl_wait()` to wait for a message, and finally call `rcl_take()` to get it.

The executor uses an [rcl_waitset_t](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/c83119c826c75fbaf6e741658927a953318832ad/rcl/include/rcl/wait.h#L39-L67) to wait for things to become ready. It puts everything - subscribers, timers, etc - it into a waitset, and then it calls [rcl_wait(...)](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/c83119c826c75fbaf6e741658927a953318832ad/rcl/include/rcl/wait.h#L376-L471). Even lower that goes to [rmw_wait(...)](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/blob/eeb5859def4af28c3aa231dfe7be30fbc31bcfaf/rmw/include/rmw/rmw.h#L2363-L2438), which is implemented by each middleware. It returns when at least one thing in the waitset has become ready to execute, and the waitset itself is modified to say what's ready. When the executor calls [rcl_take(...)](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/c83119c826c75fbaf6e741658927a953318832ad/rcl/include/rcl/subscription.h#L207-L271) it already knows there's something to do - sort of.  Sometimes a middleware will say a subscription is ready but it's not because of a message. I forget when and why this happens, but checking `taken` says if there's a message or not.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2021-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2021-01-26**:
@NEngelhard did this answer your question?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2021-01-27**:
Thanks! That was what I was looking for. I'm exchanging DDS with a different message passing library that has it's own spinOnce so that I have to process all messages before spinning the other library that fills the ROS2-queues. It now works with subscribers, but not yet with services, but that needs some more work until I can ask a good question. Thanks again for your support!